# How to switch to the QEMU control panel with -nographics?

Tags: terminal.app, qemu

It seems that the terminal does not recognise CTRL+ALT+2 when typed, so I don't know how to quit the QEMU emulation, or switch to the QEMU control panel.

I am running Mac OSX Lion, and I type

```
$ qemu-system-arm -M verdex -pflash flash.img -nographic -sd sdcard.img
```

to start QEMU emulation of an ARM system in the Terminal. I learned from [this site](http://909ers.apl.washington.edu/~dushaw/ARM/) that typing CTRL+ALT+2 should work, but the only thing that happens to me, is that a "2" is printed on the command line of the virtual operating system. Any ideas on what could be wrong? Is this a Mac specific issue? (The same problem occurs in both terminal.app and iTerm2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165158/how-to-switch-to-qemu-monitor-console-when-running-with-curses

Comment: The whole Qemu monitor Ctrl-Alt-2 thing only works in some environments.  But using the Telnet-based monitor works on more platforms.  Count on that and you should be able to make it serve you well.

Answer (score 3):

The combination to enter the control panel is ctrl-a  * release keys *  then; c

Typically written: ctrl-a c

Similarly, to quit: ctrl-a x

Comment: To exit the control panel, use the same sequence.  This was not obvious to me.

Answer (score 3):

**`-monitor`**

This is another option:

```
qemu-system-x86-64 -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -serial mon:stdio
```

and then on another shell:

```
telnet localhost 45454
```

and now you can send monitor commands from inside the telnet, e.g.:

```
quit
```

The advantage of this method is that it allows you to automate further with:

```
echo quit | telnet localhost 45454
```

`-serial mon:stdio` required to keep Ctrl+C working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49716931/how-to-run-qemu-with-nographic-and-monitor-but-still-be-able-to-send-ctrlc-to/49751144#49751144

Full QEMU test command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -append 'root=/dev/vda console=ttyS0' -kernel 'bzImage' -drive file='rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2' -nographic -serial mon:stdio
```

on Ubuntu 17.10, QEMU 2.10.1.